# SINON - an issue mocking a middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocking, sinon

I have the following middleware in a Node.js REST API

```
const Authorized = (req, res, next) => {
if (!req.headers["authorization"]) {
    res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
} else {
    jwt.verify(req.headers["authorization"], PRIVATE_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(403).send("Forbidden");
        } else {
            req.businessId = decoded.businessId;
            req.roleId = decoded.roleId;
            next();
        }
    });
}
```

};

As you can see I'm adding to variables to the request object

In the mockup of my tests I'm trying to do this:

```
sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    sandbox.stub(Authorized, "Authorized")
        .callsFake(async (req, res, next) => {
            req.businessId = businessAux.id;
            return next();
        });
```

But this doesn't work and my actual function to be tested needs this variable:

```
listPermissionAndRolesByPk() {
    this.app.get(`${config.API_PATH}/permissionrolebypk`, Authorized.Authorized, async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.query.id;
        const businessId = req.businessId;
        if (!id) return res.status(400).send(messages[23].message.replace("${object}", "Permission Id"));
        try {
            const permission = await PermissionDAO.getPermissionAndRolesByPk(id, businessId ? businessId : 0);
            if (permission) {
                return res.status(200).json(permission);
            } else {
                return res.status(404).send(messages[8].message.replace("${object}", "Permission"));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(error.httpCode).send(error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, one oddity is that your original method is not async, but your `callsFake` is giving an async arrow function.

Comment: Still that isn't the problem I tested removing `async` and still in the request object there isn't no variable like a normal request would have.

Comment: How did you export and import the middleware. Please include the code.

Comment: @slideshowp2 How I did import the middleware in the application or in the tests? In each controller I import the middleware `const Authorized = require("../middleware/requestAuthenticator");` and I used it like you see in the piece of code of `listPermissionAndRolesByPk `